# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate not returning a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to change a saved date to mountain standard time using NSDateFormatter but it  doesn't seem to be working.

it's outputting 
"currentDate: 2013-02-22 23:20:20 +0000 date With date formatter:  other 2000-01-01 07:00:00 +0000" 
to the console.

It looks like the string isn't being created correctly, but I seem to be calling it in the same way I've seen it called normally.

Suggestions?

```
    NSTimeZone * mtnTimeZ= [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"];

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:mtnTimeZ];

    NSString * timeZ = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

    NSDate * newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeZ];
    NSLog(@"currentDate: %@ string With dateFormatter: %@ date made from string %@", currentDate, timeZ, newDate);
```

Comment: You're not showing us the output of that NSLog -- the text is different.  Double-check that you've pasted the CURRENT code (did you press save?) and the latest results from that code -- something's out of sync.

Comment: What's the format of the saved date? The code you posted is a bit contrived. You would never go from `NSDate` to `NSString` and back to `NSDate` with the same formatter that has no specific format set. Tell us what you really have saved and what to convert it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the style for specify date and time formats in order of it to work:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
NSString * dateCurrentTZ = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"]];
NSString * dateMSTZ = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Date In Current Time Zone: %@", dateCurrentTZ);
NSLog(@"Date In MST: %@", dateMSTZ);
```

In case you want to specify your own format:

[NSDateFormatter Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Then look for "Fixed Formats" based on iOS & Mac OSX ver. you are targeting.

Comment: From apple's documentation it looked like the formatter would adhere to the given date's format but apparently not. Really wish apple would  allow iOS to use OSX's dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone method for NSDate, it would make things a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following line:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

like this:

```
NSTimeZone * mtnTimeZ= [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:mtnTimeZ];

NSString * timeZ = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

NSDate * newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeZ];
NSLog(@"currentDate: %@ string With dateFormatter: %@ date made from string %@", currentDate, timeZ, newDate);
```

Comment: @HotLicks You have to specify a format. If you the documentation no default date and timezone style are set be Apple, so one need to specify it to work or define fixed format.

Comment: I got currentDate: 2013-02-23 22:04:17 +0000 string With dateFormatter: 2013-02-23 03:04:17 date made from string 2013-02-23 10:04:17 +0000 from your code, Not sure what's goin on there